# Can't seem to return JSON in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On a hover event over a single item in a gallery I want to populate an info window with results from an AJAX call.  I'm new with CI and I can't seem to figure out why I can't make that work.  I have checked other posts.. no love.

Can anybody point my error out to me?

Here is my javascript function firing on a hover

```
function showDataWindow(){
    $.post('index.php/home/getMoreInfo', { ID: thisID},
        function(data) {
             var moreInfo = $.parseJSON(data);
             alert(data); // just checking
             .. build my HTML with results and fade in ..
});};
```

Here is the relevant method in my controller

```
public function getMoreInfo()
{
    $answer = "unsigned";
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $this->load->model('Artist_model');
    $assocReturned = $this->Artist_model->get_more_info($ID);
    echo json_encode($assocReturned);
}
```

And here is my Artist_model

```
public function get_more_info($ID)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM NOIRusers WHERE UID=$ID");
    $assoc = array();

    foreach($query->results() as $r) // there should be only one result .. do this different?
    {   
        $assoc['memberID'] =$r['UID'];
        $assoc['firstName'] =$r['UFname'];
        $assoc['lastName'] =$r['ULname'];
        .... a lot more like this ...
    }
    return $assoc;
}
```

I keep getting a 500 (Internal Server Error).  I've got my Database library loaded btw.

I think the problem is how I am handling my database response.  As I understand it .. $this->db->query() gives me a database object, which I then iterate into an associative array through the foreach.  I return that array to my controller which then json_encodes it and echoes it back to javascript.

What am I not getting right?

Comment: results() is not a function in the codeigniter database class. This might not be the solution to your problem however.  You should check out the generating query results with codeigniter page here:http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html.  If you were looking for result() you are also not using that correctly.  I suggest you emulate the examples on the database class page to get the correct syntax.

Comment: I think @WillSampson is right and this might be the case. Change `results()` with `result()` and see how it goes. Also if you want each column value to be in an array you should use `result_array()`, if you want them to be in an object, you should use `result()`, but refer to them like `$r->UID`, `$r->UFname`

Comment: @Vlakarados Hmm.. i did just change to result() and I'm still getting a 500 error.  And if I'm passing the data to be JSON encoded in the next step I'll end up referring to the values the same at the end, right?  Does it matter if I use array or result_array?

Comment: @K.K.Smith the way you are trying to generate results now you will want to use result_array() since result() generates an object not an array.  Let us know if that changed anything for you.

Comment: Problem solved.  You all were right.. I was using - after correction - result() which gives me an object (accessed like $obj->property) but I was trying to access it like an array ( $array[key] ).  I went for an object.   thanx!

Comment: @K.K.Smith Glad it helped! Refer to the answers below as they are pointing out some great practice!

Answer (score 4):

I would give credit to Zathrus for pointing out GZIP compression as the cause.

In CodeIgniter, you cannot output directly from a controller with GZIP compression enabled. The reason for this is because the output class gets interrupted. To avoid this issue, do something like the following:

In your controller:

```
$data['json'] = json_encode($assocReturned);
$this->load->view('json', $data);
```

In `views/json.php` (or whatever view you make):

```
<?php echo $json;
```

I realize you've already solved your issue and it wasn't related to GZIP compression, but should you eventually optimize your site and enable it in CI, you will run into this issue if you keep your code the way it is.

Comment: I'll give some love for that useful potential snag to look out for in the future.  But it was not my problem here.  And I guess I'm just learning how to troubleshoot through an MVC system.  But your tip confuses me, since I'm not doing a view reload.. I'm just trying to get the data from the controller back to an AJAX call.  Am I not understanding?

Comment: Loading a view does not mean an extra http request, nor a reload. Loading a view just means that you're telling CI where/how to output the data. It is, for all intents and purposes, the same as outputting directly from the controller, but because of the way CI's output class works, it is necessary for what you're doing if GZIP compression is enabled (in CI).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have error reporting turned on in CI? That should tell you what't wrong.

It can also be a wrong .htaccess file.

Or - if you're using GZIP compression, it will cause problems if you try to echo things out yourself. CodeIgniter uses [views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) that are compatible with its gzip outputting - echo will break the page and fetch you a 500 error.